# ember: waiting until instance-initializer completes before doing anything else

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an instance-initializer (below) for a shopping cart.  The cart is an ember-data model because I am persisting to the back end.  I am wanting *all* instances of my ember app to have a cart ID assigned *before* doing anything else.

I know the ideal is async, but item prices on the site are dependent on the cart. I am finding it would be easier to handle both the front end and the back end if I can depend on the cart always existing.

How can I tell ember to not do anything else until the cart instance-initializer completes and the ember-data cart model resolves?

My instance initializer:

```
export function initialize(appInstance) {
    let CartService = appInstance.factoryFor('service:cart');
    let cart = CartService.create();

    // check if there's a cart id present in localStorage
    if (window.localStorage) {
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            //previous cart id found
            cart.loadCart(window.localStorage.getItem('cart'))
        } else {
            // no LS cart found, create a new one
            cart.createCart();
        }
    }

    appInstance.register('cart:main', cart, { instantiate: false });
    appInstance.inject('route', 'cart', 'cart:main');
    appInstance.inject('controller', 'cart', 'cart:main');
    appInstance.inject('component', 'cart', 'cart:main');
}

export default {
    name: 'cart',
    initialize
};
```

It handles two scenarios: a cart exists in localStorage, or no cart exists, create a new one.  Those two methods are:

```
// cart service methods

loadCart(jsonCart) {
    // called from instance-initializer when a previous cart is found in localStorage

    let incomingCart = JSON.parse(jsonCart); // the raw cart in LS

    this.get('store').findRecord('cart', incomingCart.cartid).then(cart => {
        cart.setProperties(incomingCart);
        cart.save();
        set(this, 'cartObj', cart);
    });
},
createCart() {
    // called from instance-initializer when no prev cart is found

    let cart = this.get('store').createRecord('cart');
    cart.save().then(response => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(response));
    });
    set(this, 'cartObj', cart);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same issue at these days. I've found these alternatives:

1. Using application initializers (not application instance initializer): Application initializers have [deferreadiness method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_deferReadiness)
   to defer the readiness of the application. I think this is not applicable for my situation, because my services are not initialized yet.
2. Using `sync` remote call: Browsers warn about this. It is bad for user experience.
3. Waiting async operation in `application route`: The application route's model hook will return a promise that will be satisfied when all async opearions are finished. Shown in this [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/dfd0c4ab0fc6eaa5905bb71a146e185a?openFiles=services.deferer.js%2C).

I think I'll prefer the third one. But I'm open for new ideas.